Does the C runtime clear the home slots of args prior to function calls?
When you call a function from C/C++, that has some params smaller than 64bits, does the runtime zero out the stack memory at the home location of those params? Or does the top of each param contain garbage?
The space for each param is 8 bytes (64bits), but they might represent 8, 16, or 32bit values.
Assume that the params are not passed by register, as this question pertains to any param, not just the first 4.
void foobar(bool a, i32 b, float c, i64 d)
{
    int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;    
}

----------------------------------------
# Stack Frame #

[... Previous StackFrame ...] // <HIGH ADDRESS>
[d]
[c]
[b]  // Do the top 32 most-significan-bits of param 'b' contain garbage, or zero?
[a]
[ReturnAddr]
[Saved rbp]
[x]
[y]
[z]


// read 'b' value -- if the top 32bits of 'b' contains garbage, rax has wrong value.
mov rax, qword ptr[rbp+24]


The language standards do not define a stack memory. All is up to compilers. See as the example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/what-are-the-debug-memory-fill-patterns-in-visual-studio-c-and-windows

Why should reading b involve reading a qword? Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/rd6TssjPf. There is only 32 bits read.

Your question is tagged x86, yet you talk about rax register. I changed the tag to x86_64.

@Daniel Langr -- Image that this is manually created assembly, not compiler generated.

@Dess Obviously, in the manually created assembly, you should also read only a 32 bits in this case. Why would you read more? If you don't respect the size of the binary representation of a parameter, then you will likely end up with an incorrect program.

"The space for each param is 8 bytes (64bits)" This very much depends on the implementation.

@KenY-N: Interesting. What's an example of a 64-bit implementation that does not space arguments at 8byte boundaries?

@Dess Don't know, but there might be one, or some combination of compiler flags or something might do it?

@DanielLangr -- You're making an argument of what the programmer should or shouldn't do. I'm not taking a position on that. My question pertains to the actual behavior of the runtime.

@Dess Then, this question is not related to C/C++. Note that, e.g., C++ itself doesn't define how parameters are "passed" to functions. It even doesn't recognize the concept of CPU stack at all. This is all a matter of ABI and machine-code level. You can ask how a particular compiler will behave in such a situation, but then your question should be restricted to that compiler (implementation) instead of being generic (or, at least, to some particular ABI). Because there is no generic answer.

Your foobar will take its args in registers, not the stack, whether this is x86-64 SysV or Windows x64.  But yes, in both conventions registers can also have high garbage; see Is a sign or zero extension required when adding a 32bit offset to a pointer for the x86-64 ABI? - as an undocumented extension to the calling convention, GCC and Clang extend narrow args to 32-bit, but only clang relies on that when reading them.  ICC-classic didn't, so can't always safely call code compiled with clang.

@PeterCordes: I appreciate you traveling back in time to 8 years ago and pre-answering exactly the esoteric question I was going to have today. Simply amazing, Peter.

Firstly, no, there is no guarantee that the padding between parameters which are passed via the stack is zeroed out.
This is specified e.g. in the System-V ABI, 3.2 Function Calling Sequence, which is used on Unix-like systems.
However, it also doesn't really matter what is in the padding bytes.
To read the value of a bool b that has been passed via the stack, the compiler could emit
mov al, byte ptr[rbp+24]

This ignores the upper 56 padding bits at the pointer.
If the upper 56 bits of RAX should be zero, movzx could also be used as follows:
movzx eax, byte ptr[rbp+24]


I can agree with this answer for compiler generated code. However, there is also manually created assembly, which is what I'm interested in.

Thank you for linking to that document and specifying the section. I read it, and agree with you that "there is no guarantee that the padding between parameters which are passed via the stack is zeroed out." -- That is the answer to the question as posted.

@Dess why tag c++ and c  when you wanted to ask about assembly ?

Neither x86-64 SysV nor Win x64 would pass the OP's bool a in memory for that caller.  It's the first arg so it would be in DIL or CL respectively.  (With the rest of the register not necessarily zeroed.)  Oh, but your example is bool b so I guess you're not talking about the OP's function.

@PeterCordes OP's question contains "Assume that the params are not passed by register". Of course, you would only begin passing bool on the stack once you have run out of registers normally, or with C variadics.

Oh, I see.  And they say "not just the first 4.", which implies Windows x64, so the appropriate calling-convention docs would be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=msvc-170 which unfortunately doesn't seem to say anything about high garbage for args narrower than 8 bytes.  (Their mention of "home slots" for args is also consistent with MS terminology (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/stack-usage?view=msvc-170) where Win x64's shadow space provides "home slots" for register args to be dumped into.)
